# Sort posts by title, sort array by largest number

Tags: php, get-posts, sort

I am using the post to display attorney verdicts and case details. 
The post title is the verdict amount entered as a string. (no $ "," or ".")

I am formatting the title using PHP number format:

```
EX: User enters 360137 in the post title.
    $number = get_the_title(); 
    $ammount = number_format($number);

    echo '<h1>$'. $ammount . '</h3>';

Returns $360,137
```

This is working as expected.

Using get_posts() I can 'orderby' => 'title' and 'order' => 'DESC' or 'ASC'

```
$args = array( 
'category' => 64, 
'orderby' => 'title', 
'order' => 'DESC' ); 

$myposts = get_posts( $args ); 
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
```

While this is working it does not recognize the length of the value. For example it will display 30,000 before 2,100,000. How do I get this list sorted by ASC or DESC AND by string length?

I want to show the largest verdicts first.

9,000,000

2,100,000

90,00

3,000

Comment: I agree this is a duplicate and I did not find the above mentioned post. What is proper procedure. Delete this post?

Comment: It can be closed as duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easier if you rearranged how you're going about this. Rather than putting a numerical value for the title, why not put it as a custom field. You can still show all your posts and orderby your custom field as a numerical value using `meta_value_num`. [More info](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters).

Here's a topic on the WordPress Support forums for someone trying to accomplish the same thing: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/orderby-title-doesnt-sort-numbers-correctly?replies=38

*Please note what user esmi says:*

> Can I point out that:
>
> [...]
>
> correct from a programming pov? Those "numbers" are actually strings -
>   not numeric integers.

PS -- `echo '<h1>$'. $ammount . '</h3>';` should be `echo '<h1>$'. $ammount . '</h1>';`

Comment: I did catch and correct the H1 tag issue. Thank you.

Comment: Here's something that might get you going int he right direction, if you're deadset on using numbers as the post title: http://www.fldtrace.com/wordpress/custom-post-types-numeric-title-order

Comment: Thank you, I am not set on doing it that way. The `meta_value_num` should work great. I do want to avoid using a custom post type unless there is a good reason.